# Taylor series of $\ln x$ at $x=e$

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Like in the title, I need to find taylor series of $\ln (x)$ at $x=e$ I was thinking about changing $\ln (x)$ to $\ln (x-e+e)$ but it lead me to nowhere.

Comment: Use the standard form, yes? $f$ expanded around $x = a$ is

$$f(x) = f(a) + f'(a)(x-a) + {1 \over 2!} f''(a)(x-a)^2 + ...$$

Comment: @SimonS I should add that I'm supposed to not use derivatives.

Comment: What are you supposed to use?

Comment: I should use that $ln (1-x) = -\sum\frac{x^n}{n}$

Comment: Ok. Olivier has written out an answer in (almost) that form below.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** You may just write
$$
\ln (x)=\ln (e+x-e)=\ln e+\ln \left(1+\frac {x-e}e\right)=1+\ln \left(1+\frac {x-e}e\right)
$$ and use the standard expansion
$$
\ln (1+u)=u-\frac{u^2}2+\frac{u^3}3-\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{u^n}n+\cdots,\qquad |u|<1,\tag1
$$ by putting $u=\dfrac {x-e}e$.

Comment: This is an interesting situation (at least, to me). In a comment, the OP precises that he/she is not supposed to use derivatives. The problem is : how do we build Taylor series without using derivatives ? So, the series mentioned in comments just comes from the clouds ! Funny, isn't it ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici
It seems to be the expansion $e^{x}=1+x+\frac{x^{2}}{2!}+\frac{x^{3}}{3!}+\ldots $ can be percieved as a canonical one. For example, if we define an exponent as a function, which satisfies to the functional equation $f(s+t)=f(s) \cdot f(t)$ (up to a constant), one of the approaches is to solve it in the algebra of power series and the exponent is one of its solutions. Taking it into account, we can find the logarithm series expansion, evaluating the inverse exponent.

Comment: I cannot disagree with you, for sure. But, I feel that we can be looping in circles for ever (who came first : the chicken or the egg ?).Cheers :-)

Comment: We were expanding functions like $e^x$ or $sinx$ and so on by counting derivatives, and this is one of the exercises in which we have to use the basic expansion to find expension for another function. :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to compute the derivatives in $x=e$. Since:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\,\log x=\frac{1}{x},\quad \frac{d^n}{dx^n}\,\log x = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!}{x^n}$$
in a neighbourhood of $x=e$ we have:

> $$ \log x = 1+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{ne^n}(x-e)^n.$$

Comment: Hi Jack ! The OP is not supposed to use derivatives and this take us to a funny situation. Look at my comment to Olivier Oloa. Cheers :-)